# Is there a way to match the color of two stacked elements when transparency is applied?

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of divs that are stacked on top of one another. The background color is set to red with rgba and alpha being 0.5 for both. Visually, the top div's color looks a shade darker than the bottom div's color. I'm assuming this is just because of the color theory as the top color blends with the bottom to make it look a bit darker when transparency is added. Is there a way to make those two colors match with some property or a trick? Or is it the way it is?

The following is the sample code:

```css
.main{
 background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
 color: black;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.topper {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  Blah
</div>
<div class="topper"></div>
```

Comment: The expected behaviour of topper is to make the undelying element more red, that is why you set a half transparent, red layer to begin with. It is not clear what you want, I mean, why topper is not fully transparent ?

Comment: @vals This question is kinda a mockup. I have an element that has an overlaying div element and I have a toolbar that allows the user to change the background color and transparency. So, when I set the bg color to red and add some transparency, both of these elements will get that color and transparency added and looks like in the above demo. So, what I am trying to achieve is - to make those two elements (i.e., the overlapped top element) to look the same instead of two different shades.

Comment: But, why don't you set the background of the overlaying element  fully transparent?

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to do what you want. The result is exactly the same.

**First method** is to change the alpha value of the top div to zero, which actually makes it transparent.

```css
.topper {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

**Second** method is cleaner:

```css
.topper {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Huginn23/pen/RwyxYGm) I made, to observe how colors interact with transparency when stacked.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

Just delete the background-color property from the lower div.